# Showing bootstrap pill active by default

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap ul and li like the following:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#Tab1">Tab1</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#Tab2">Tab2</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#Tab3">Tab3</a></li>
</ul>
```

But the only problem is that on loading of the page, it does not show Tab1 colored by default.
I would like to show the Tab1 colored. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance.

Cheers!

Comment: `<li class="active"><a data-toggle="pill" href="#Tab1">Tab1</a></li>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just place **`active`** class on **`li`** which you want to show on page load

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<ul class="nav nav-pills" role="tablist">
  <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#profile" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#messages" aria-controls="messages" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#settings" aria-controls="settings" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a></li>
</ul>

<!-- Tab panes -->
<div class="tab-content">
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="home">Home</div>
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="profile">Profile</div>
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="messages">Message</div>
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="settings">Settings</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @right_click_2 note that this will set the default on load, but you will still need to add some jquery or javascript to change active for the clicked tab on select.

Comment: thanks. i am in the process of checking t his. seems like it will be the correct answer

Comment: @JoshAdams No need to add jQuery. Bootstrap will take care of it.

Comment: No, bootstrap doesn't take care of it when you have "active" set in your code. It keeps it as "active", unfortunately. Any chance to solve this?

Comment: @Siyah You can see in the snippet above. Its working fine

Answer (score 0):

you can put class active to li you want set default.Such as:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="pill" href="#Tab1">Tab1</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#Tab2">Tab2</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#Tab3">Tab3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
  <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="/home">Home</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="/profile">Profile</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="/message">Messages</a></li>
</ul>
```